# Write a data frame to an existing Access (.accdb) table in R

Tags: r, ms-access, odbc, rodbc

I've spent some time using the `RDBOC` library to write a data frame to an Access table but gave it up after realizing that it suppresses white spaces from column names.

Now I'm trying the `dboc` library, for which I've found fewer references on the web.

The connection to the database is created by writing:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), .connection_string = paste("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=", my_db_path, sep = ""))
```

After that I tried two alternatives for writing the data frame to a table:

```
dbWriteTable(con, "existing_table", my_df, append = TRUE)
dbWriteTable(con, "existing_table", my_df, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Both returned the error below. Column names in the data frame match the column names in the table.

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1763: HYC00: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Optional feature not implemented
```

Any guidance on how to debug this error?

Comment: rodbc may be trying to send integer values as BIGINT, which Access ODBC does not support. To check that, [enable ODBC tracing](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Troubleshooting-%E2%80%93-Generating-an-ODBC-trace-log#windows) and run your (failing) code. Turn ODBC tracing off again, then open the SQL.LOG file and search for `SQL_BIGINT`. If you find it then check the rodbc documentation to see if you can tell it to send integers as SQL_INTEGER instead of SQL_BIGINT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DBI` with `odbc` batches inserts by default. Access doesn't support batch inserts. That's the optional feature that isn't implemented.

To do normal inserts, specify `batch_rows = 1`:

```r
dbWriteTable(con, "existing_table", my_df, append = TRUE, batch_rows = 1)
```

Also discussed [on GitHub](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/263).

Regarding debugging, ODBC tracing is generally a good move, as Gord Thompson noted, but this is a known issue.

Comment: It works, thank you, but it's too slow. I even tried to write to an Access file in my desktop rather than on the network, but this didn't improve speed. Any guess?

Comment: Well... Access just isn't that fast. The details really depend on exactly what you're inserting. It can be a good idea to write the data to Excel first, then import the data from Excel into Access. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70977554/7296893